# How to configure index.js with hapi npm for deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-deployment, package.json

I received this project to deploy, which uses the hapi npm that I am not familiar with. I am able to run it successfully localy but when I try to deploy it I get an error, on **`heroku`** the error is:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

I think maybe I have to change something in the index.js maybe the port or the host inside server const?
Here is my **`index.js`**

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');


const readDir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);

const server = Hapi.server({
  port: 3000,
  host: 'localhost',
  routes: {
    files: {
      relativeTo: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    }
  }
})

const start = async () => {
  await server.register(require('vision'));
  await server.register(require('inert'));

  server.views({
    engines: {
      html: require('handlebars')
    },
    relativeTo: __dirname,
    path: 'templates',
    layout: 'layout-other',
    layoutPath: 'templates/layout'
  });

  // Static files
  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
      directory: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        listing: true
      }
    }
  });

  require('./routes')(server);

  server.start();
}

start();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing `script: start`. In your `package.json,` means you are missing to `configure` where to `start` 
check your `package.json` file you should define that like this

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
}
```

If your app has a build step that you’d like to run when you deploy, you can use a  [**Postinstall script**](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) in `package.json:`

Answer (score 1):

`npm start` is a script that is created in your `package.json` file.
You can check more about it [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#default-values)

An example of a `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "node-js-sample",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "description": "A sample Node.js app using Express 4",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "somescript":"do something"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

`npm start` will run the "start" script. Which means it will run `node index.js`
`npm somescript` will run the "somescript" script. Which means it will run `do something`